# My JS code works on online compilers but fails test on leetcode. It ouputs [1] on other compilers but shows [3] in leetcode

Tags: javascript

```
let ourMap = new Map();
function getKey(value) {
  return [...ourMap].find(([key, val]) => val == value)[0]
}

var topKFrequent = function(nums, k) {
    let result = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        // result.push(undefined);
        if(ourMap.has(nums[i])){
            ourMap.set(nums[i],ourMap.get(nums[i])+1);
        }
        else{
            ourMap.set(nums[i],1);
        }
    }
    
    for(let j = 0; j < k; j++){
        let max = Math.max(...ourMap.values());
        let s = getKey(max);
        result.push(s);
        ourMap.delete(s);
    }
   
    return result;
};

let s = [1];
let result = topKFrequent(s,1)
console.log(result);
```

leetcode 347 topKFrequent
My JS code works on online compilers but fails test on leetcode. It ouputs [1] on other compilers but shows [3] in leetcode

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Leetcode may be calling the function *more than once* - which is a problem because your current implementation defines `ourMap` only once at the top level. Define everything inside `topKFrequent` (or make all outer functions not depend on outer variables).

```
const topKFrequent = function(nums, k) {
    const ourMap = new Map();
    function getKey(value) {
        return [...ourMap].find(([key, val]) => val == value)[0]
    }
    const result = [];
    // ...
```